# Does JSF have a way to get the tag handlers in the current view?

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, omnifaces

We have a JSF taglib we're using that dynamically adds components to a view. One of these components is an alternative button... the command button dynamically adds a an actual command button as a subcomponent of itself (in addition to some other useful stuff).

We want to use `<o:validateBean />`. Normally we'd implement a `PostAddToViewEevnt` listener and just move the components from the parent to the child. HOWEVER, Omnifaces' `<o:validateBean />` is implemented as a `TagHandler`, not a `UIComponent`.

Since the `apply()` method of the `ValidateBean` `TagHandler` is called in the `RESTORE_VIEW` phase, one idea would be to implement a `PhaseListener` that gets ahold of the view and moves the `<o:validateBean />` to the correct component.

I can't seem to find a JSF API to peruse the view declaration and grab any `TagHandler`s and modify the layout however.

Even if you don't have an exact answer, if anyone could comment on modifying layouts with a `TagHandler` it made lead us to the right answer. Thank you!